# Can I do a HTTP POST through a new window.open using Angular?

Tags: angular

I am having difficulties to do an HTTP post request in my angular app. from right-sidebar component whenever user click on a button this function called up:

```
//right-sidenav.component.html
info() {
    this.infoService.getInfo().subscribe(layers => {
      if (layers) {
        let handler: any = window.open(
          "/info-window",
          "Info",
          "width=1200,height=500"
        );
        handler["tableData"] = [];
        handler["signals"]= this.signals
        handler["tableData"]["tableNumeric"] = layers[0];
        handler["tableData"]["tableString"] = layers[1];
        handler["tableData"]["tableDatetime"] = layers[2];
      }
    });
```

from the response, I am getting 3type of table info that will be displayed in a pop-up window. I am also sending signals information into the pop-up window. and whenever the user clicks on `signals` it will do an HTTP post request. But here I am getting problem. I can not do the Http request. I can't see any request is made through `inspect --> Network`.

I am not sure whether I can do the HTTP request from a pop-up window or not.

Here is my pop-window:

```
//info-window
constructor(public infoService: InfoService,
    protected apiService: ApiService,) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const int = setInterval(() => {
      if (!window["tableData"]) {
        return;
      }

      this.tableNumeric = new Array(window["tableData"]["tableNumeric"]);
      this.tableString = new Array(window["tableData"]["tableString"]);
      this.tableDatetime = new Array(window["tableData"]["tableDatetime"]);
      this.signals = window["signals"];
      this.table.push(this.tableNumeric, this.tableString, this.tableDatetime);
      clearInterval(int);
    }, 500);
  }

  displayPlotting() {
    if(isNull(this.selectedSignal)) {
      return
    }
    let response = {};

    response["table_info"] = {
      data: {}
    };
    for (let signal of this.selectedSignal) {
      response["table_info"]["data"][signal.key] = signal.name;
    }
    response["results"] = {
      table: ["table_info"]
    };
    console.log("InfoService -> response", response);

     this.apiService.post("info/plot", response).pipe(
      map(result => {
        console.log("InfoService -> result", result);
        return result;
      })
    );
    //let plot = this.infoService.getPlotting(this.selectedSignal)
    //console.log("InfoWindowComponent -> displayPlotting -> plot", plot)

  }
}
```

Here is the `apiService` code:

```
//apiservice.service.ts 
post(route: string, data: any, withCredentials?: boolean, loading: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
    if (loading) {
      this.$loading.next(true);
    }
    const url = this.localStorageService.getDjangoHost() + route;
    this.saveRequestParam('post', url, data, withCredentials);

    return this.postTemplate(url, data, withCredentials)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => this.handleError('post', error, url)),
        finalize(() => {
          if (loading) {
            this.$loading.next(false);
          }
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        map((result: any) => {
          this.handleLeftSideMessage(result);
          return result;
        })
      );
  }
```

can someone please help me to solve this issue? How can I do the Http post request from a pop-up window??

Comment: Please add `ApiService` source code

Comment: updated. @emtei

Comment: How does your "this.postTemplate(...)" function look like!? Normally you would use angular http client to make http request within an angular app... https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: we are using httpclient module. normally u just have to send the request type using API service and then the service will do the rest. i am just wondering if i can do the reuqest from window pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post` method in your ApiService returns `Observable`. An Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it. [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)

Simplest way will be:

```
this.apiService.post("info/plot", response).pipe(
  map(result => {
     console.log("InfoService -> result", result);
       return result;
  }).subscribe();
```